# mvc 3 asp.NET access resources from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3.
I declared resources strings in a resource file Order.resx in App_GlobalResources and I need to access to those strings inside my controller action.
The Resource namespace is not recognized as in the views.

Comment: What is the syntax you are using in the Views? What have you tried in the *Controllers that is not recognized?

Comment: in the view I use @Resource.Order.MyString syntaxt and in the controller I tried to use Resource.Order.MyString but "Resource" is not found by the compiler

Comment: Do you have the right `using` statement at the top of the Controller file?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the Custom Tool Namespace value in the Resource file properties is set to:

```
PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
```

and do a full solution rebuild. Then try seeing whether you can see the resource namespace in your view.

Comment: I'm using **GlobalResourceProxyGenerator** and I have no problem to use the resources in my views. The problem is concerning controllers actions.

Comment: Ensure it is Resources. and not Resource.

Comment: FYI GlobalResourceProxyGenerator is the "Custom Tool". The "Custom Tool Namespace" should be PublicResXFileCodeGenerator

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that my controller project is different than the project where the resources are located.